# Parsing NSString substrings gives random EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

I'm working on a simple OBJ parser for iOS and I've been encountering a problem with group parsing. My method is pretty raw as the OBJ is meant for a specific application : I take the content of the OBJ file and split it by group and parse the group specific string. The goal is to return an object for each group or an object of all groups (user chooses). Problem is that I get EXC BAD ACCESS at random when doing that. At first I thought it was a memory leak in my parser, so I did a test with the full content, not split, since the OBJ parser also supports it. And no exception, nothing, it works, even if I do it a million times (eventually the ipad memory melts down though).

Here's some sample code to show where my problem is :

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file"
                                                 ofType:@"obj"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
// works
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [parser parse:content];
}
NSArray* data = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"delimiter"];
// not working - random EXC BAD ACCESS
for(NSString* obj in data)
{
    [parser parse:obj]; // doing a for loop with an index is the same
}
// works, even though it's pointless
for(NSString* obj in data)
{
    [parser parse:content];
}
```

So, the part where the parser tries to parse obj throws EXC BAD ACCESS pretty randomly at these places :
- inside the parser when trying to interpret the nsstring at different levels (may it be indices, names, vertices, etc...)
- just after finishing to completely parse the current (any in from the array) nsstring and returning to loop
- after parsing all the nsstrings, throwing in the main.m

No details whatsoever. I tested NSZombie to check if it was a dealloc problem, nothing throws, though I sometimes get "memory read fail for ". Sometimes I say, as it's totally random, and I usually get nothing.

Some details that might have their importance:
- I'm using ARC, and it's an obligation regarding my work
- Parsing is fairly long ~50-200ms depending on obj file size
- Parsing is totally synchronous, nothing is done off thread in this situation
- memory usage is small, and on loading full file, there's no visible leak on debug
- you'll find it pretty obvious : I'm a total beginner at objective-c

thank you for your time!

Comment: the error must be in parser ...

Comment: the code above looks fine to me at first glance

Comment: Have you run Analyzer against your project??

Comment: (That error is not caused by a memory leak, it's caused by zombies.)

Comment: Yes analyzer is totally clean, and like i've mentionned, I can't detect any zombies via NSZombies. And parser works fine since I can instanciate the whole file into the GPU with opengl es 2.

Comment: I gather you've omitted a lot of code.  And I suspect in the omitted code prior to the componentsSeparatedByString call you've accidentally freed something that you're keeping a pointer to and will reference/modify (or perhaps bogusly free again) in your `for` loop.

Comment: (This assumes you're not simply doing bogus pointer arithmetic or array addressing somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* data = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"delimiter"];
```

Is the OBJ file really separating on the string 'delimiter'? Or should this be

```
NSArray* data = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

(I seem to remember OBJ splits on comma)

Comment: Actually, delimiter is the string "g ", as OBJ files have groups organized by this line identifier. I just put "delimiter" as a placeholder. So this means that every line under this identifier belongs to current group, until next "g ". This works fine, on debug view, data contains the correct strings.